# new and delete char* causes exception

Tags: c++, winapi

I have the following code, but it causes an exception. Without itoa "games" I don't think there's a problem. TextOutA is because I use winapi.

```
char* p1 = new char[2];
itoa(10,p1,10);
TextOutA(hDC,5, currenty,p1,2);
delete[] p1;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your stringbuffer is too short

itoa overruns the buffer capacity in writing the null termination character.

```
char* p1 = new char[3];
itoa(10,p1,10);
TextOutA(hDC,5, currenty,p1,2);
delete[] p1;
```

I suggest you make the buffer big enough to accomodate the full integer range.

**Edit** Just in case, elaborating on the string stream suggestion:

```
#include <sstream>

//....
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << 10;
    std::string s = ss.str();
    TextOutA(hDC, 5, currenty, s.c_str(), s.length());
}
```

Comment: I suggest using `std::ostringstream` and `std::string`, and not having to worry about the size of the buffer.  (In simple cases like this, you can just use `boost::lexical_cast<std::string>`.)

Comment: @James: Added an example on using string streams in C++ fashion, in case the OP wanted a hint on how to use that

Answer (score 2):

You have not allocated enough space to store "10", because, like all C strings, it takes N+1 characters, where N is the length of the string. The last character is the null terminator. You should allocate 3 characters (or more). Or use `snprintf`. Or `std::stringstream`.

Here are a number of [much better alternatives](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill19.htm) to using `itoa`, assuming you don't need specialized radix formatting (though some of them can do that too).

Answer (score 0):

You don't allocate enough space for the string.

```
char* p1 = new char[2];
itoa(10,p1,10);
```

`p1` is 2 bytes long, which is only sufficient for 1-character string (the other character is the nul terminator). You should make it long enough to hold any possible result, which would be 11 for a 32-bit system and base=10.